# AES-NI on Dell Vostro 3360

Tags: linux-kernel

I don't have AES-NI available on my Dell Vostro 3360 laptop. Why? Does this machine not support it?

My `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 782.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 3392.17
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/287887 makes it sound like this is a BIOS bug...

Answer (score 0):

Check against this list: http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced/?s=t&AESTech=true. It also might be an option in your BIOS, although I doubt it.

Comment: I checked. Processor should have aes-ni according to this website. In bios I have no options like that.

Comment: OK, so your CPU supports AES-NI. Check your kernel config for a line like CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL . It should be compiled in as a module usually.

Comment: Yes, I have such module but without aes among cpu flags I can not load it: modprobe aesni-intel
ERROR: could not insert 'aesni_intel': No such device

Comment: What I said is: is that option enabled at compile time? For example on my machine : $ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m . That means it's compiled as a module. If above command returns nothing, you will have to recompile your kernel for it to support that option.

Comment: You edited your comment...Anyway, what distribution is this?

Comment: I have CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m. But fact I cannot load this modules is an effect. Cause is lack of "aes" cpuinfo. In you can load modules it means that you have "aes" in cpuinfo. Btw, show me your /proc/cpuinfo, if you can. I have debian, but kernel is 3.6.11.

Comment: My CPU doesn't support AES. Please paste the output of "l s -lRa /lib/modules/$VERSION/kernel". Also the output of "dpkg -l module-init-tools && cat /etc/issue". $VERSION must be the same as the kernel you are running.

Comment: I have good module -- I use linux since 2002 and I can compile kernel. I think you confuse cause and effect.

Comment: OK. Try 'modprobe aes' and see if it works. I'm trying to help, so you could at least have given me the info I asked for. The aes module is an alias for several AES-related modules, so modprobing it should do what you wish.

Comment: @schaiba AES shows up in `/proc/cpuinfo` regardless of if the aesni-intel module is loaded.

Comment: You're not alone - Google finds several hits on Dell Vostro 3360 not supporting AES-NI. Could be it has a different CPU or just the BIOS not supporting it somehow.

Comment: (deleted my last comment) I found a cpuinfo of a different system here http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Samsung_Series_5_Ultra_530U3C-A02PT - same cpu (family/model/stepping/freq). which includes aes. Only difference seems to be the microcode version, not sure if microcode can be related to aes support?

Comment: If you are right, and I start to share your impression, it means that Dell is shit company. Look at that https://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails?driverId=R309835#OldVersion After few month the product has been released Dell decided to support all function given by Intel.

Comment: @AlojzyBomba This is an answer. It's an OEM hardware company disabling this feature. You pointed to another model with a BIOS update enabling it. Just get in contact with Dell to get one for yours - we can't do anything about it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Many companies are not enabling AES feature in laptops. For my Asus I found solution here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/582628-aes-ni-support-truecrypt-sandy-bridge-problem-15.html#post8002488

I followed that few steps and successfully modified my BIOS. Maybe it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check on intel's site,

Just see if `aes` is one of your CPU flags by `grep aes /proc/cpuinfo`

(Works for me:  i5 2450m)

If you got a match, it's supported.

Comment: for its processor the information [on intel website](http://ark.intel.com/products/65707) says it's supported, but there is no such flag on `/proc/cpuinfo`. I think this difference is the reason he asked the question in the first place